# Open .txt files with VS Code on Mac

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

Hi I use Visual Studio Code to run a C-Code, which opens a .txt file.
The problem is: I don't know where the file should be placed on my Mac, so it can open it seamlessly.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: place it in user folder root `~/` or `/Users/$USER/`

Comment: Suggest you use an environment variable to hold the directory name.  Use `getenv(3)` to retrieve the value and prefix your filename with it.  That is far more flexible than having fixed directory names.  If the environment variable is not set then you can default to `.` (current directory).